# Extracting a part of String in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a field that returns a string value in this format `xxxxxxx(xxxxx)`. Now I need to extract the content of the string inside () as well the ones before (). How can I achieve this?

Comment: so you need to the values as two columns?

Comment: You have a poorly designed column then. If these are actually two separate pieces of data, they ought to be stored in their own, separate, columns. If so desired, you could then have a computed column that assembles them together and adds the brackets, for display purposes.

Comment: Yes , I need them as two columns.@TechDo

Comment: Its not a poorly designed Column. Its just a client requirement that they wanted to separate certain part of a code. @Damien_The_Unbeliever

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
declare @str varchar(100)

set @str='xxxxx(aaa)'

---- extracts xxxxx
select SUBSTRING(@str,0,CHARINDEX('(',@str)) 

---- extracts aaa
select SUBSTRING(@str,CHARINDEX('(',@str)+1,CHARINDEX(')',@str)-CHARINDEX('(',@str)-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
declare @var nvarchar(100)='xxxxxxx(xxxxx)'

select @var, 
    LEFT(@var, charindex('(', @var, 1)-1), 
    replace(right(@var, charindex('(', @var, 1)-1), ')', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

`
 Dont have much idea about sql server.

bt in oracle you can achieve this as follow:

```
SELECT SUBSTR('xxxxxxx(xxxxx)',0,instr('xxxxxxx(xxxxx)','(')-1)            AS first_part,
SUBSTR('xxxxxxx(xxxxx)',instr('xxxxxxx(xxxxx)','(')+1,instr('xxxxxxx(xxxxx)',')')-instr('xxxxxxx(xxxxx)','(')-1) AS second_part
FROM dual;
```

so try to find the respective syntax.
`substr` is self explanatory.
and `instr` returns the position of 1st occurrence of a character in a given string.

Answer (score 0):

TEchDo answer is perfect, he just missed out one other `replace` function for the second column.

```
declare @var nvarchar(100)='xxxxxxx(xxxxx)'  

select @var AS Source, LEFT(@var, charindex('(', @var, 1)-1) AS FirstColumn,   
replace(replace(right(@var, charindex('(', @var, 1)-1), ')',''),'(','') AS SecondColumn
```